# Error while sending an email through a for loop for expiry date reminder

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I have a sheet that has expiry dates + contractors names.

I'm trying to send an email, whenever the expiry date is to expire within 90 and 60 days.

It sends for the first cell that satisfies the condition but after that it shows me an error with the omail.to or omail.subject and omail.send saying "the item has been moved or deleted".

This is the code:

```
Sub reminderautomail()      

' reminderautomail Macro      
Dim mydate1 As Long      
Dim datetoday1 As Date      
Dim datetoday2 As Long          
Dim x As Long         
Dim aax As String      

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application      
Set olApp = CreateObject("outlook.application")        
Dim olmail As Outlook.MailItem      
Set olmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)        

For x = 4 To 29    
    aax = Cells(x, 3)    
    mydate1 = Cells(x, 9)    

    datetoday1 = Date     
    datetoday2 = datetoday1         
    expi = (mydate1 - datetoday2)        

    If expi <= 90 And expi >= 60 Then    
        Cells(x, 10) = "YES"    
        Cells(x, 11) = expi    

        olmail.To = "email address"    
        olmail.Subject = " An Agreement is about to expire soon "    
        olmail.Body = " This agreement is about to expire in " & Cells(x, 11) & " days from today's date" & " the agreement is for " & aax    
        'olmail.Display    
        olmail.Send    

    ElseIf expi <= 60 And expi > 0 Then    
        Cells(x, 10) = "YES"    
        Cells(x, 11) = expi    
        olmail.To = "email address"    
        olmail.Subject = " An Agreement is about to expire soon "        
        olmail.Body = " This agreement is about to expire in " & Cells(x, 11) & " days from today's date" & " the agreement is for " & aax        
        'olmail.Display        
        olmail.Send         

    ElseIf Cells(x, 10) < 0 Then        
        Cells(x, 11) = "Expired !!"      
    End If     

Next     
Set olApp = Nothing     
Set olmail = Nothing     

End Sub
```

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkRa1.png)
Here the code already in the previous iteration sent me an email reminder with no errors, but when it goes to the next iteration it shows this error.

Comment: On which line you get this error when you go to Debug Mode ?

Comment: whenever it satisfied the condition it send the mail, but later when it satisifed the condition it shows error in: olmail.send & olmail.subject & olmail.body

Answer (score 0):

The Object olMail will be missing after it has been send on the first succesfull iteration and sending the e-mail.

"the item has been moved or deleted" is most likely the error you receive.

To prevent this, make sure you create a new E-mail object every time you match the criteria as follows:

```
If expi <= 90 And expi >= 60 Then    
    Set olmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)   

    'Do your things

    olmail.Send
ElseIf expi <= 60 And expi > 0 Then
    Set olmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 

    'Do your things

    olmail.Send  
ElseIf Cells(x, 10) < 0 Then        
    Cells(x, 11) = "Expired !!"      
End If
```